# Read ASCII and binary from file in c++

Tags: c++, binary, fstream

How can i manage to open a file and read some fixed (lets assume n) lines of ASCII code, and after that switch to reading BINARY from the same file starting with the n+1 line in C++?

Comment: If you've opened the file with `fopen` in text mode, you can re-open it in binary mode with `freopen`. If that's what you mean.

Comment: and will it keep reading from n+1 line, not reopen the file?
I was looking for a c++ solution via fstream, but i guess that's fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the mode without reopening because the fstream uses system calls to open files which in turn do not allow a mode change. You can use [tellg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/tellg/) / [seekg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/) to save and later restore the reading position, respectively.

Comment: I guess I'll mark your answer as accepted since I was thinking the same, but I waited for another possibility. Thanks